# Why is wordpress removing some unicode characters (e.g. some emojis) when I save my post?

Tags: posts, filters, bug

Try making a new post, pasting this string of emojis: "" and then saving that post as a draft. When I do this (in WP version 4.7.4), it removes the emojis.

First I create the post:

---

### [image]

After clicking "Save Draft":

---

[image]

The culprit here seems to be the crab emoji: If you take it out the the emoji string everything works fine. I'm guessing this is a bug where wordpress isn't handling new emojis properly? Can anyone help me disable the "sanitisation" that's causing this (if it's safe)?

It's strange that wordpress removes *all* the emojis when the crab emoji is present. I think it's got to do with the 2015 [unicode 8.0](http://emojipedia.org/unicode-8.0/) update because I tested it with the scorpion emoji which also came with that update and it causes the same problem.

P.S. I wasn't sure on the correct tags, please let me know if there are more appropriate ones.

**Edit:** Note that this isn't a rendering problem since the characters are actually *gone* (not just invisible or something) - they've been filtered out at some point in the save process.

Comment: how do you insert them?

Comment: ... and generally if somethign expected to work and it isn't on a vanilla wordpress, the best thing to do is to open a bug in the wordpress trac

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - I just copied them and pasted them into the post (they're unicode characters, not images). Yeah, I actually tried to report this but for some reason it wouldn't let me login (or reset my password). I'd appreciate it it someone could post it as an official bug report. I don't urgently need a fix - I mainly posted it here as a bug report and to help others who come across similar issues.

Comment: it works for me in 4.7.4. First I was wondering about the font in your editor (it’s not _Merriweather_). Please set it to default and test it again. And: What’s about your database charset (should be UTF8)? Please check your wp-config (DB_CHARSET).

Comment: @st Hmm that's strange - maybe it isn't a bug then. Thanks for checking. It's using [utf8mb4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074492/what-is-the-difference-between-utf8mb4-and-utf8-charsets-in-mysql). I'm not sure what you mean by "set it to default"? I haven't changed it (didn't know you could), but also, how could the wordpress editor font affect the ability to save certain unicode characters? Fonts are just visual, right? It seems to be set to "Noto Serif" by default (from inspecting css).

Comment: I also do not have any problem with that emoji, which is why I asked about the "where from" because this might have been a copy paste problem. In addition what @st said about fonts, fonts need to support rendering of characters, if they will not support they will not be rendered (I guess it also depends on browser/os fallbacks). The weird thing is that all of them are not displayed.

Comment: I am going to close vote it as "too localized" right now as there is most likely some other unkown factor in play here

Comment: Ah okay, yeah it must be something wrong on my end. Thanks for the help anyway! I'll keep investigating.

Comment: I also have this problem. The characters are stripped from my posts when I save. Can’t for the life of me work out why, though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade your database and table charsets to utf8mb4 (WordPress 4.2+’s default). I’ll not provide instructions as to how to do this beyond “backup first and diff and compare pre and post database dumps!” Set aside enough time to recover from any trouble.

I had the exact same problems as you, and fixed it by upgrading to a database charset that actually supports 4-bit emojis.